# are default values in python global?

Tags: python, static, default-value

What output would you expect for this python snippet?

```
    def some_fn(arg=[]):
        arg.append('value')
        print(arg)

    for i in range(5):
        some_fn()
```

**I** would expect arg to be `[]` every time I call `some_fn()` without arguments. As a matter of fact the instance of the default value is being kept.

Has my expectation just been wrong or is this a strange behavior in Python?
At least in C++ default values are being assigned every time I call the function.

Comment: Ok, I found http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm but I still find this strange and misleading...

Comment: Why is this misleading? Defaults are part of the *function object*. They are not global, but your function object may well be.